# Making HTTP requests inside Ruby threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I start a number of threads (using Ruby Threads class) that call some function that makes HTTP requests. It takes a lot of time to receive an answer (thats why I decided to use threads to make more calls simultaneously). But it seems that threads are waiting one another and I don't gain any time using this approach. Is this issue Ruby-related? Does waiting for an answer to HTTP requests block also other threads from executing?

```
num_threads = 10
threads=[]

(1..num_threads).each do | thread_no |
  puts "Creating thread no." + thread_no.to_s
  threads << Thread.new{migrate_from_CSV(thread_no)}
end
```

migrate_from_CSV function calls Cucumber step that (after manipulating data) makes following call:

```
    @agent = Mechanize.new if @agent.nil?
    @agent.post(@path, account_json.to_json, HEADERS)
```

This POST request takes long time to complete, so I want to call it multiple times simultaneously.

Comment: What's your implementation?

Comment: Are you using Rubinius or JRuby, they are proper thread implementations, regular CRuby (aka MRI) does not.

Comment: I added information about implementation in original post

Comment: No, waiting on IO, like an HTTP response, should not block other threads from executing, even in MRI.  But I don't know about Mechanize, it may not be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer. If I change

```
@agent = Mechanize.new if @agent.nil?
```

to

```
@agent = Mechanize.new
```

it seems that solves the problem.